# How to pandas groupby specific value in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with multiple columns using with added a new column for age intervals.

```
# Create Age Intervals
bins = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100]
df['age_intervals'] = pd.cut(df['age'],bins)
```

Now, I've another column named `no_show` that states whether a person shows up for the appointment or not using values 0 or 1. By using the below code, I'm able to groupby the data based on `age_intervals`.

```
df[['no_show','age_intervals']].groupby('age_intervals').count()

Output: 
age_intervals   no_show
  (0, 5]        8192
 (5, 10]        7017
(10, 15]        5719
(15, 20]        7379
(20, 25]        6750
```

But how can I group the `no_show` data based on its values 0 and 1. For example, in the age interval (0,5], out of 8192, 3291 are 0 and 4901 are 1 for `no_show` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way would be to group on both columns and use `size()` which returns a Series:

```
df.groupby(['age_intervals', 'no_show']).size()
```

This will return a Series with divided values depending on both the `age_intervals` column and the `no_show` column.